# ASA Ironport WCCP: allow specific host to access only specific url

Tags: cisco-asa

I need to restrict specific inside host (e.g. 10.0.0.1) to allow accessing only specific URL (e.g. https://www.eestipank.ee/currency/rates/export/csv/custom?imported_at=undefined&chart_start_at=26.12.2017&chart_end_at=02.01.2018&chart_step=day&currency_code%5B0%5D=USD).

I have ASA 5545 and IronPort in my disposal.

Could you please advise which steps to be taken to configure ASA WCCP and IronPort to achieve result?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Alexei

Comment: Quick search on Cisco support forums gave me a perfect guide. You will need to use regex to find the specific string and block it. Please remember that the URL you've specified above has attributes that might be very difficult to search for. Link to guide: [https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/asa-url-filtering-without-a-websense-or-n2h2-smartfilter-server/ta-p/3116352](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/asa-url-filtering-without-a-websense-or-n2h2-smartfilter-server/ta-p/3116352)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I apologize for delay with accepting answers. I did what I have to with URL filtering as @Cown suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have a similar setup where we allow a particular user access to one site only.
We setup a Access/Decryption policy called "Limited User" and an Identification profile which specifies the users IP address which is exempt from authentication. 
This ID uses a custom URL category which specifies what site we want to allow them to access.

Works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I appreciate effort and value advice. As I changed data source from https to http I managed to get away with URL filtering.